# Why dispatch method is taking long time to call target method in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have this method

```
class RunningQuizAuthenticationView(APIView):

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(time.time())
        return super(RunningQuizAuthenticationView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request: Request, key: str) -> Response:
        print(time.time())
        .....
        ......
```

Now, once I get both the time, I take the difference of this time, the difference time is about 30 ms, can you explain to me why this is taking so much time, for the login request it takes about 0 ms but for other requests it takes a long time to reach target method from dispatch method, please help me, Thank you

Comment: You don't say where you get the time difference and what they are supposed to be. Can you be more specific ? time.time() will just display a time...

Comment: Once time gets printed on the console, I take it and take the difference using a calculator. As we know dispatch is the method which calls our target method.

Comment: What operations are there in your other views? I/O examples please.

Comment: 30 ms is not a long time! It is 0.03 second. How fast do you want it to be?

Comment: Finally, I got the bottleneck, It is inside dispatch method of APIView, it calls  "perform_authentication" method which is taking about 30ms, I will solve it now, Thank you guys for your responses :)

Answer (score 1):

I got the bottleneck, It is inside dispatch method of APIView, it calls "perform_authentication" method which is taking about 30ms,

```
def perform_authentication(self, request):
        """
        Perform authentication on the incoming request.
```

`` Note that if you override this and simply 'pass', then authentication
    will instead be performed lazily, the first time either
    `request.user` or `request.auth` is accessed.
    """
    request.user ``

Comment: yes for us also , most of the request time is spending in this method, as per the comment, we can over-ride this method and simply do 'pass' then authentication will be performed lazily and request time is getting reduced drastically(from 25 seconds to 3 seconds).....is there any impact if, we do the way suggested in comments ?